# send dynamic html table from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I dont know if its simple, but is there any way to send the complete html table from a page to popup window? The table is created dynamically from server data, now I want to pop this only table out of its original page. The user changes the data in html table, but will not save back on server. So getting data from server in popup is not practicle, something jquery can do this, but dont know how. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
enter code here
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to retrieve the HTML content of the table and send the return string as variable when you create the new page or dialog

```
$("#TABLE_ID").html();   // <-- gets you the entire HTML table code
```

and make sure that the table has the ID:

```
<table id="TABLE_ID">...</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simple use `html()` attribute of jquery like this

```
$("#YourTableId").html();
```

and set html of your div in popup

```
$('#YourDivId').html($("#YourTableId").html());
```

more info here

http://api.jquery.com/html/